# Delphi 2010 accessing to frames inside a TIFF

Tags: delphi, graphics, delphi-2010, tiff

I just tested I can access to TIFF images in Delphi 2010 with the classic

```
image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(MyTiffFile);
```

Simply using this line of code I can load the first frame of a TIFF file into a TImage component. But when a TIFF file is a multiframe one. How can I get the rest of images contained in a TIFF file?

Comment: I think for this you will need to use a third party control. I have no experience with Delphi and its controls, but multi-page tiffs are normally not part of the standard functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the standard way, no.

But you can try a 3rd party component. Here are some:

- [LibTiff for Delphi](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/delphi.html) (free) allows you to work with the official Tiff implementation tapping the full 'power' of Tiff format - however it can be a little difficult to walk through the internal Tiff directory to achieve what you want. But perhaps you can send an email to the Aware Systems and ask them how to do it.
- [HiComponents ImageEn](http://www.hi-components.com/nimageen.asp) (commercial) - even if the site is very simple, it seems that it is one of the best graphic libraries around.
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) (free) - very well known image processing library. Has Delphi/FPC bindings.

...there are also other alternatives free and commercial but some of them (like GraphicsEx) doesn't know to read multi-page Tiff and for others I don't have so much experience in order to give you an impression.

HTH.